# Error: NJS-047: poolAlias "default" not found in the connection pool cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, async

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão utilizando **Connection Pool** para construir uma **API Nodejs** consumindo dados do **Oracledb**, segui a seguinte [documentação](https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-database-basics/). Porém, ao tentar fazer a conexão recebo o seguinte erro:

> Error: NJS-047: poolAlias "default" not found in the connection pool
>   cache

Tentei colocar um *poolAlias* manualmente na configuração de conexão ao Oracle mas nada resolve.

A classe de configuração da conexão, **database.js**, está da seguinte forma:

```
module.exports = {
 hrPool: {
   user: "meuUsuario",
   password: "minhaSenha",
   connectString: "localhost/XE"
 }
};
```

A classe que é chamada para fazer a conexão e executar uma consulta está da seguinte forma:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = require('../config/database.js');

async function initialize() {
  const pool = await oracledb.createPool(dbConfig.hrPool);
}

async function close() {
    await oracledb.getPool().close();
}

function simpleExecute(statement, binds = [], opts = {}) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let conn;

      opts.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;
      opts.autoCommit = true;

     try {
       conn = await oracledb.getConnection();

       const result = await conn.execute(statement, binds, opts);

       resolve(result);
     } catch (err) {
       reject(err);
     } finally {
       if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
         try {
           await conn.close();
         } catch (err) {
           console.log(err);
         }
       }
     }
   });
 }

module.exports.simpleExecute = simpleExecute;
module.exports.close = close;
module.exports.initialize = initialize;
```

Não consegui identificar o problema, visto que utilizo async nas chamadas assíncronas e a documentação segue o mesmo modelo...

Apenas como informações adicionais, o **index.js** inicia a aplicação da seguinte forma:

```
  async function startup(){
  console.log('Starting application');

  try {
    console.log('Initializing web server module');

    await webServer.initialize();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);

    process.exit(1); // Non-zero failure code
  }
}

startup();
```

E o **web-server.js** que é chamado na função **startup()** tem o método **initialize()** da seguinte forma:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const webServerConfig = require('../config/web-server.js');
const database = require('./database.js');

let httpServer;

function initialize() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const app = express();
    httpServer = http.createServer(app);

    // Combines logging info from request and response
    app.use(morgan('combined'));

    app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
      const result = await database.simpleExecute('select user, systimestamp from dual');
      const user = result.rows[0].USER;
      const date = result.rows[0].SYSTIMESTAMP;

      res.end(`DB user: ${user}\nDate: ${date}`);
    });

    httpServer.listen(webServerConfig.port)
      .on('listening', () => {
        console.log(`Web server listening on localhost:${webServerConfig.port}`);

        resolve();
      })
      .on('error', err => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}
```

O método **initialize** executa o `database.simpleExecute('select user, systimestamp from dual');` que acaba dando o problema de conexão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após diversas tentativas, cheguei a uma solução:

Verificando o código interno do oracledb do Node, reparei que o método getConnection recebe alguns atributos de conexão como parâmetro:

```
function getConnection(connectionAttributes: ConnectionAttributes): Promise<Connection>;
```

Portanto, bastou inserir a configuração do pool como parâmetro para que o método funcionasse, antes estava assim:

```
conn = await oracledb.getConnection();
```

Ficou assim:

```
conn = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig.hrPool);
```

Que esta solução possa ajudar muitos, visto que nem mesmo a [documentação](https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-database-basics/) apresenta uma solução para o problema.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, my `getConnection` method was working perfectly until it stopped. Searched everywhere for an answer and yours helped

Comment: @SirajKakeh really glad to read this!!